# What does T mean in ATP rankings

Tags: tennis, ranking

On the atptour site, next to the player's ATP rank there is the letter T. What does it mean?

https://www.atptour.com/en/players/rogerio-dutra-silva/sc73/rankings-history

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the ranking, you can see that this is always shown next to several players - so it means that the players are tied for the same position.

For example, here is one screenshot from ATP website:

[image: screenshot ranking]

The screenshot is taken from the current status of this page: https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles/?rankDate=2019-11-25&countryCode=all&rankRange=1001-1100

This question contains more detail on criteria that are user (beside the points) in the ATP rankings: [What tie-breaker is used in the ATP ranking, when two players have the same number of points?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4161) (So T next to the ranking means that the players have the same number of points and also the other ranking criteria are the same.)